# EC2 Upstart job: Stop on runlevel never called pre-stop

Tags: amazon-ec2, upstart

I'm using EC2 and I have a pre-stop script that is calling curl.  From what I can tell the curl never gets called.  I'm trying to do stop on shutdown or stop on runlevel [056].  Neither seem actually call the pre-stop script when I shutdown the EC2 instance from the GUI.  Originally I thought EC2 was terminating the networking before starting the shutdown, but now I just think stop is never called at all.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

We really need to see that job to comment appropriately. If you are unable to share that information, I suggest you look at:

- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#debugging
- http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/#debugging-a-script-which-appears-to-be-behaving-oddly